# Which data structures to use for a node-based editor?

Tags: c++, user-interface, data-structures, nodes

Some programs (i.e. sound-synthesis, procedural texture generation, ...)  give their users complete freedom to arrange various capabilities of the program in an arbitrary manner through a graphical editor. The user can place one or multiple "nodes" (each of which represents some kind of function which generates one or more outputs from one or more inputs) and patch/connect them together in any way desired to generate the final output.

I wonder what the best representation for such a software might be in terms of necessary data structures, both for the generator system itself as well for its graphical representation. I'm especially puzzled about how to model the fact that node in- and outputs might be of various data types and only some of them might be valid depending on the node type.

So how to model:

- Node input/output values
- Nodes themselves (inheritance?) and their connections
- The generation process, propagating from the start nodes to the output node

Comment: This is pretty open ended as a question... interesting as it is.

Comment: Not seeing any C++ here.

Comment: Sounds like it might be worth investigating the `boost::graph` library.

Comment: @Peter Wood: You're right, of course. I was just thinking that from a performance point of view one would probably use C++ so I added it, just in case it would make a difference (but most likely it won't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been involved with a few systems like this. There are a number of different ways of doing things. But one common way I've done it in the past is to have Node objects link to other Node objects. Nodes contain an action object via some IAction interface. The user specifies somehow the concrete action object that implements the IAction interface at a particular node (this would also typically involve specifying some state for the object, e.g. parameters for a filter to be applied).

Then there's a framework that initiliases (compiles) and executes (runs) the graph, and arranges to call the IAction interface with the inputs to the node when the inputs are ready, and passes the outputs to downstream nodes. This is a pretty simple algorithm: run all nodes in parallel that have all their inputs present (starting with nodes with no inputs), and put the rest on a wait queue until their inputs are present.

This is just one flavour of how to do it; there are many variations, and a lot of systems out there that that use this technique as you've pointed out. There are some frameworks too ([TPL Dataflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/17/10212961.aspx) is one such, *if* I've understood it right).

Re your question about how to make sure that connections are consistent between nodes, this comes down in my opinion to a choice between how much the framework does and how much nodes do. At one extreme, the framework can rigorously match connection types at graph "compile time"; at the other the framework can leave it to nodes to check at "run time". The latter may well be appropriate if most connections are just the same type, e.g. they're all byte streams, for example.

btw It's probably easier in Java or C# (or a.n.other HLL) than in C++, because there's more support for interfaces, reflection, loading objects in on the fly, etc (so for example in C# you can easily specify a type for an object and dynamically create it from a stream, whereas you have to roll that yourself in C++).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the Observer pattern, and in particular signals/slots systems for this type of thing. 
[Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/signals.html)

A project I worked on a while back using C++ used signals/slots to allow different audio synthesis modules to be connected dynamically at run-time by a user. There can be a trade-off in terms of performance though.

As for modelling the different possible inputs, you could make a signal object to contain the actual data as a void pointer and a string or enum specifying the data type which receiving classes assume is correct during processing. When your user initially connects these objects a kind of contract could be returned ('these are the types that this object sends') and the actual validation could be done before processing starts.